# A Comprehensive Color List For OpenGL With Associated Names

Tags: c++, opengl

In OpenGL programming you can define vertex coloration by using the glColor3f function; this is typically implemented by defining a float value between 0.0f and 1.0f. So glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f) would be red, pretty basic. I was wondering if someone could link me to some documentation that shows every single permutation of colors with names(or just a comprehensive list). This would be easier than having to remember that glColor3f(0.98f,0.625f,0.12f); makes "Pumpkin Orange".

I found this excerpt from the superbible: http://opengl.czweb.org/ch03/040-043.html I am wanting something like that but much larger.

Comment: There are 2^(32+32+32), or 2^96 possible colors. It is somewhat hard to list them all. And that is only if you do not include the possibility of double based buffers (and ignoring alpha). With double buffers it would be (2^(64+64+64)) which is a rather significant number.

Comment: This isn't really specific to OpenGL. Googling "rgb color names" gives quite a few likely looking resources. Note that for most you'll have to convert (0-255) values to (0->1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [this table](https://web.archive.org/web/20180301041827/https://prideout.net/archive/colors.php) and you want the numbers on the far right.

Comment: It is rather far from "all possible colors" however. About a factor of 825293359523586849932749482 off. :)

Comment: +1; or even the float listing to put directly in the source code

Comment: @perh I did state in the OP that I would settle for a "Comprehensive List". The above person delivered, so he will get accepted. I need this for simple copy and paste reasons. I like your precision with maths though; cool to see how many colors exist.

Comment: @Zac Which is where my intentions were.

Answer (score 4):

An RGB color picker (like [this one](http://www.rgbtool.com/) eg.) will allow you to easily find the RGB values (integer or float) for any given color.

For a list of common colors (with their names), many can be found all over the internet. A comprehensive one is maintained on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A%E2%80%93F) eg.

Comment: To the downvoter, may I ask why ?

Comment: Specifically asked for associated names, not just the raw output.

Comment: @Krythic : You also asked for all possible permutations - I provided an approach for both your questions : an RGB color picker will give you all possible colors, and a named list will give you commonly used ones only.

Comment: You're correct, I should have redacted that request; I will fix the title immediately. Oh, and not sure why, but I cannot link your name for a proper reply.

Comment: @Krythic : when replying to an answer, the name of the answerer is implied, so doesn't need to be specified explicitly.